# Network issues with .NET sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I have a basic asynchronous socket server.  Recently I have been getting intermittent periods where one of the connections gets the following errors on reply from a TCP peer:

```
Exception message:
The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.

Exception stacktrace:
at System.Text.Encoding.ThrowCharsOverflow()
   at System.Text.Encoding.ThrowCharsOverflow(DecoderNLS decoder, Boolean nothingDecoded)
   at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, DecoderNLS baseDecoder)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteCount, Char* chars, Int32 charCount, Boolean flush)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex, Boolean flush)
   at System.Text.DecoderNLS.GetChars(Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteIndex, Int32 byteCount, Char[] chars, Int32 charIndex)
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer()
   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
   at MyServer.TcpReceiveMessages()
```

I suspect the traffic is getting mangled on a specific network route (other TcpListeners and peers elsewhere in the application/network communicate 100% fine all the time).  What steps can be taken to better pinpoint this and fix it?

(Note, I've already done packets captures, and the incoming packet processing that is causing the exception *looks* fine, i.e. the payload seems to contain the text I want.  I say *look* because there are identifiable parts of the payload that should be there, however there are also binary parts which when mangled would not be obvious immediately.)

Simplified version of the listener:

```
private void TcpReceiveMessages()
{
   TcpClient tcpServer = new TcpClient();
   string address = "some_address";
   int port = 80;
   tcpServer.Connect(address, port);
   StreamReader srReceiver = new StreamReader(tcpServer.GetStream());

   StringBuilder wholeMsg = new StringBuilder();
   string partialMsg = "";

   while (tcpServer.Connected)
   {
      try
      {
         //Save a partial portion of the reply:
         partialMsg = srReceiver.ReadLine();

         //Reply complete:
         if ( partialMsg != null && partialMsg == "")
         {
            response = wholeMsg.ToString() + partialMsg;

            //Misc response processing code.
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         //Do logging that leads to the above exception message/stacktrace
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If your capture showed no issues then your suspicion that the data is getting mangled on the network is probably incorrect. How do you determine the size of your output buffer? Is it always the size of the sockets read buffer or do you try to calculate it based on some part of the data read?

Comment: No, I don't calculate it.  I have a TcpClient called tcpServer and am in essence simply doing `tcpServer.GetStream().ReadLine()`, which will read to the end of the line, i.e. while the stream is not dry.  There are no \r\n anywhere in the stream, and the Read is known to be complete when this ReadLine returns an empty string.  Each ReadLine in effect returns a partial part of the message, which is appended to the end of a totalMessage variable.

Comment: TCP can send 1 "packet" as maybe 120bytes, the next packet maybe 200bytes, ** that is an example **, am trying to emphasize that the size of packet is not "consistent" due to TCP mechanisms, hence you need to check on the 'markers' to distinguish the actual data... being ignorant of the `ReadLine` method is a dangerous thing! best to use binary stream reader and just read until you have found the markers and reconstruct the data. In short, craft a better mechanism altogether :)

Comment: Can you post some of your code to give a bit more insight? I don't think this is a Sockets\TcpClient\Network problem.

Comment: @SpaceghostAli sure thing.  I just put up an abridged version of the listener.  Also, this only seems to happen to one box, and works (and has worked flawlessly) elsewhere for some time.

Comment: You can't really use `ReadLine()` with binary data. That's probably what you are hitting - stream reader trying to find new line char in some binary block and overflowing its internal buffers.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem machine is not being sent UTF8 encoded text? That may also cause the problem.